# Edge Extraction Suggections OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vision

Im looking for suggestions to improve my algorithm to search for parts in the following image

[image]

so far I have the following

```
GaussianBlur(canny, canny, Size(5, 5), 2, 2);
Canny(canny, canny, 100, 200, 5);
HoughCircles(canny, Part_Centroids, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, 30, 100, 50, 50, 60);
```

My edge detect output looks like this

[image]

and Im using a HoughCircle to try to find the parts.  I havent been having great success though because the HoughCircle seems very fussy and often returns a circle that isnt really the best match for a part.

Any suggestions on improving this search algorithm

EDIT:

I have tried the suggestions in the comments below. The normalization made some improvements but removing the canny before hough circles altered the required settings but not the stability.

I think now that I need to do something like the hough circles with very open thresholds and then find a way to score the results. Are there any good methods to score the results of hough circle or correlate the results with the canny output for percentage of match

Comment: As the contrast is low in this image, I would first normalize it before doing the Canny operation.

Comment: You are not supposed to apply canny before finding HoughCircles, because HoughCircles itself will apply canny edge detection

Comment: You should improve your image quality. Get some proper illumination, focus your lens. Crap in -> crap out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I would post my solution as someone may find my lessons learned valuable.

I started by taking several frames and averaging them out.  This solved some of the noise issues I was having while preserving the strong edges.  Next I did a basic filter and canny edge to extract a decent edge map.

```
    Scalar cannyThreshold = mean(filter);
    // Canny Edge Detection
    Canny(filter, canny, cannyThreshold[0]*(2/3), cannyThreshold[0]*(1+(1/3)), 3);
```

Next I use a cross correlation with increasing diametered templates and store matches that score over a threshold

```
    // Iterate through diameter ranges
    for (int r = 40; r < 70; r++)
    {
        Mat _mask, _template(Size((r * 2) + 4, (r * 2) + 4), CV_8U);
        _template = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        _mask = _template.clone();
        _mask = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        circle(_template, Point(r + 4, r + 4), r, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, CV_AA);
        circle(_template, Point(r + 4, r + 4), r / 3.592, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2, CV_AA);
        circle(_mask, Point(r + 4, r + 4), r + 4, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);

        Mat res_32f(canny.rows, canny.cols, CV_32FC1);
        matchTemplate(canny, _template, res_32f, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED, _mask);
        Mat resize(canny.rows, canny.cols, CV_32FC1);
        resize = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        res_32f.copyTo(resize(Rect((resize.cols - res_32f.cols) / 2, (resize.rows - res_32f.rows) / 2, res_32f.cols, res_32f.rows)));
        // Strore Well Scoring Results
        double minVal, maxVal;
        double threshold = .25;
        do
        {
            Point minLoc, maxLoc;
            minMaxLoc(resize, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
            if (maxVal > threshold)
            {
                matches.push_back(CircleScore(maxLoc.x, maxLoc.y, r, maxVal,1));
                circle(resize, maxLoc, 30, Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);
            }

        } while (maxVal > threshold);
    }
```

I filter out circles for the best match in each zone

```
// Sort Matches For Best Match
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t j = i + 1;
        while (j < matches.size())
        {
            if (norm(Point2f(matches[i].X, matches[i].Y) - Point2f(matches[j].X, matches[j].Y)) - abs(matches[i].Radius - matches[j].Radius) < 15)
            {
                if (matches[j].Score > matches[i].Score)
                {
                    matches[i] = matches[j];
                }
                matches[j] = matches[matches.size() - 1];
                matches.pop_back();
                j = i + 1;
            }
            else j++;
        }
    }
```

Next was the tricky one.  I wanted to see which part was likely to be on top.  I did this by examining every set of parts that are closer then the sum of there radii, then seeing if the edges in the overlap zone are a stronger match for one over the other. Any covered circle should have little strong edges in the overlap zone.

```
    // Layer Sort On Intersection
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        size_t j = i + 1;
        while (j < matches.size())
        {
            double distance = norm(Point2f(matches[i].X, matches[i].Y) - Point2f(matches[j].X, matches[j].Y));
            // Potential Overlapping Part
            if (distance < ((matches[i].Radius+matches[j].Radius) - 10))
            {
                int score_i = 0, score_j = 0;
                Mat intersect_a(canny.rows, canny.cols, CV_8UC1);
                Mat intersect_b(canny.rows, canny.cols, CV_8UC1);
                intersect_a = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
                intersect_b = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
                circle(intersect_a, Point(cvRound(matches[i].X), cvRound(matches[i].Y)), cvRound(matches[i].Radius) +4, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
                circle(intersect_a, Point(cvRound(matches[i].X), cvRound(matches[i].Y)), cvRound(matches[i].Radius / 3.592-4), Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);
                circle(intersect_b, Point(cvRound(matches[j].X), cvRound(matches[j].Y)), cvRound(matches[j].Radius) + 4, Scalar(255, 255, 255), -1);
                circle(intersect_b, Point(cvRound(matches[j].X), cvRound(matches[j].Y)), cvRound(matches[j].Radius / 3.592-4), Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);
                bitwise_and(intersect_a, intersect_b, intersect_a);
                double a, h;
                a = (matches[i].Radius*matches[i].Radius - matches[j].Radius*matches[j].Radius + distance*distance) / (2 * distance);
                h = sqrt(matches[i].Radius*matches[i].Radius - a*a);
                Point2f p0((matches[j].X - matches[i].X)*(a / distance) + matches[i].X, (matches[j].Y - matches[i].Y)*(a / distance) + matches[i].Y);
                circle(intersect_a, Point2f(p0.x + h*(matches[j].Y - matches[i].Y) / distance, p0.y - h*(matches[j].X - matches[i].X) / distance), 6, Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);
                circle(intersect_a, Point2f(p0.x - h*(matches[j].Y - matches[i].Y) / distance, p0.y + h*(matches[j].X - matches[i].X) / distance), 6, Scalar(0, 0, 0), -1);
                bitwise_and(intersect_a, canny, intersect_a);
                intersect_b = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
                circle(intersect_b, Point(cvRound(matches[i].X), cvRound(matches[i].Y)), cvRound(matches[i].Radius), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 6);
                bitwise_and(intersect_a, intersect_b, intersect_b);
                score_i = countNonZero(intersect_b);
                intersect_b = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
                circle(intersect_b, Point(cvRound(matches[j].X), cvRound(matches[j].Y)), cvRound(matches[j].Radius), Scalar(255, 255, 255), 6);
                bitwise_and(intersect_a, intersect_b, intersect_b);
                score_j = countNonZero(intersect_b);
                if (score_i < score_j)matches[i].Layer = matches[j].Layer + 1;
                if (score_j < score_i)matches[j].Layer = matches[i].Layer + 1;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
```

After that it was easy to extract the best part to pick(Im correlating to depth data as well

[image]

The blue circles are parts, the green circle is the tallest stack and red circles are part that are under other parts.

I hope this may help someone else working on similar problems